# David's Three sisters

Tags: logical-deduction, family

I came across this in an AI test and found it rather amusing to think about.

David has three sisters. Each of them has one brother. How many brothers does David have?

Answer (score 2):

> A: Either zero or one. 
>  Most would make an unwritten assumption that David is a male, but this is not stated. It's also not stated how many sisters David's sisters have. However, not doing so: 
>  1. If David is female, there must be five siblings: four girls and one boy. One of these girls is David, who therefore has one brother.  
>  2. If David is male, there are four siblings. Three girls and one boy, who is named David. David has no brothers.

Comment: isnt it weird to answer your own question just after asking?